# How do I use the Cloud Dataflow Regional Endpoint in Europe?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to change the region of a Google Cloud Platform Dataflow job to Europe? 
I have set zone of the pipeline to `europe-west1-d` but I am unable to change to region of the job itself.
I have tried to change the region in the pipeline options, but that results in an error and only the default region is working.

`pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).region = 'europe-west1'`

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "(ff50231266257fc7): The workflow could not be created, since it was sent to an invalid or unreleased region. Please resubmit with a valid region.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
```

`europe-west1` is listed when using the command `gcloud compute regions list`

Comment: My best guess is that, since its still in beta this issue is being raised, i am not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Cloud Dataflow [Regional Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints) allow you to change the region of a Dataflow job to Europe.

Regional Endpoints are a brand new Cloud Dataflow feature. Prior to the release of Regional Endpoints, the experimental `region` option could be specified but was not used. This error message appeared because the `region` option was being specified before the feature was released.

Examples for your case (Europe):

- You can submit a job with only the [Regional Endpoint specified](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#specifying_a_regional_endpoint), (e.g. `region` = `europe-west1`), and that job will be managed and run in the `europe-west1` region; Cloud Dataflow will automatically select a zone for Dataflow workers, from this region, when you omit a zone.
- You can also submit a job with both a Regional Endpoint and Zone specified (e.g. `region` = `europe-west1` and `zone` = `europe-west1d`), and that job will be managed in the `europe-west1` region, with Dataflow workers running in the `europe-west1d` zone.

Answer (score 1):

With datafkow sdk 2.1.0 you can do this.

You can use

```
pipelineOptions.setWorkerMachineType(pipelineConfigProperties.get("worker.machine.type"));
    pipelineOptions.setNetwork("dataflow.network");
    pipelineOptions.setUsePublicIps(false);
    pipelineOptions.setZone("dataflow.zone");
    pipelineOptions.setSubnetwork("dataflow.subnetwork");
    pipelineOptions.setRegion("dataflow.region");
```

This is tested and you definitely do this in 2.1.0