# Is Google Cloud Dataflow available in the us-east region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/) state Dataflow is available in all US regions.

But when I attempt to run in `us-east1` or `us-east4`, I get this error:

> "(9a64a71b47404f4f): The workflow could not be created, since it was
>   sent to an invalid or unreleased region. Please resubmit with a valid
>   region.",

The same workflow works when `us-central-1` (though no machines are available there so it fails later...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Updating this answer to note that `us-east1` is now supported as a Cloud Dataflow Regional Endpoint **

[List of Dataflow Regional Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints)

Yes, you can run Google Cloud Dataflow in the `us-east1` and `us-east4` regions.

[`Regional Endpoints`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#specifying_a_regional_endpoint) is a feature that was released, as Beta, in September 2017 that enables you to control where a Dataflow is managed, via the `region` option.

- Currently there are only two Cloud Dataflow `Regional Endpoints` available, in `us-central1` and `europe-west1`

The existing `zone` option allows you to specify which zone your Dataflow job's workers will run.

- For your example, you would want to specify a `zone` value of
  `us-east1-b`, `us-east1-c`, `us-east1-d`, `us-east4-a`, `us-east4-b`,
  or `us-east4-c`.
- You may optionally specify a `region` value of `us-central1` to select the `Regional Endpoint` from where the job will be managed.

You may find [this related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326295/change-gcloud-dataflow-region) to be useful if you are interested in using the `Regional Endpoints` feature

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Cloud Dataflow is only supported in the following regions:

- `us-central1`
- `europe-west1`

[In the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#supported_regional_endpoints), you can find further information regarding the handled regional endpoints for Cloud Dataflow, but as you have been able to test, moving the workflow to a zone inside a region where an endpoint is available should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The intricacy is running Compute instances is available in all US regions, and specified with `--zone`, but only two regional *endpoints* are available.